# Disable payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

When the cart total is less than some specific mentioned amount, I want to disable Cash on Delivery option from payment methods in magento 1.9x.
Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login to admin panel, you can see `system > configuration > sales > payment  method > cash on delivery` => you can see  "Minimum order total"  enter the minimum amount here.

Comment: thanks a lot....its so easy but i did not figured it out. Is there any method by which I can charge a specific amount to the customer when he use Cash on Delivery but no  extra charge when he uses the payment gateway?

Comment: welcome to communtiy. thats fine. everyone is learning. check my answer for other question.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/302345/57334 anyone help me thanks